# Why is my javascript throwing a "cannot read property style of null"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, error-handling

Below is the relevant javascript code. I am passing the right value to the method, which is used for the document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = 'block' line (where the error is). I created the new ID element, and am passing that through. I don't understand.

Line with error: document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = 'block';
Its at the very end.

Thank you for the help, I am a bit new and may not fully understand the complex parts of this. I could really use the help.

```js
function addTab() {

  //create a new div element
  const newDiv = document.createElement('div');

  //create the id and add tab content class
  newDiv.id = "newtab"; //sets id name for div
  newDiv.classList.add("tablinks"); //sets class for div

  //give tab some text
  const tabContent = document.createTextNode("Testing the add tab button!");
  newDiv.appendChild(tabContent);

  //create the tab
  var btn = document.createElement("button"); //creates button
  btn.className = "tablinks"; //sets class for button

  //give onclick event to button
  var event = Event;
  btn.onclick = openTab(event, 'newtab');
  document.getElementByClassName("tab").appendChild(btn);

  //add the newly created element and its content into the DOM
  const currentDiv = document.getElementById("addnewtab");
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);
}

/* RECENT 10-K NOTIFICATION FEED START */
function openTab(evt, tabName) {

  var i, tablinks;
  let tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");

  for (let tab of tabcontent) {
    tab.style.display = "none";
  }

  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");



  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = 'block';
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: You're calling `openTab()` before you insert `newDiv` into the DOM.

Comment: The value you assign to `btn.onclick` should be a function, not the result of calling the function.

Comment: Not really. I guess im just having a hard time figuring out the solution from other questions? Im usually doing something different from them. I am making the div element and button right in the javascript method rather than passing it through.

Comment: I moved the "add newly created element..." section to before the method is called, which fixed that part. Now i am getting an error saying "Cannot read property 'className' of undefined". The last line of the javascript code.

Comment: Where is Event defined? It seems like it doesn't have a "currentTarget" property.
That part is missing in the code you posted..

Comment: if you're trying to set the onclick event of the button, you need to give the event handler method to onClick.

btn.onClick = openTab;

and maybe give the button an attribute of what id the tab linked to it has..

btn.setAttribute('tabId', 'newtab');

Comment: that way you can use it in openTab..                                                                         

document.getElementById(evt.currentTarget.tabId).style.display = 'block';

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing "Cannot read property style of null" means it's trying to access the `style` property of the element returned by `document.getElementById(tabName)`.

If this element is not found (returns null), then you'll see exactly the error message you have.

To avoid the error, I recommend adding a type guard before accessing the `style` property:

```
let tabEl = document.getElementById(tabName);
if (tabEl) {
  tablEl.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no element with the id that is given for tabname.
try moving:

```
 const currentDiv = document.getElementById("addnewtab");
 document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);
```

in addTab function (before the call to openTab)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
  //give onclick event to button
  var event = Event;
  btn.onclick = openTab(event, 'newtab');
```

You're calling the `openTab()` event immediately during the assignment, not calling it when the button is clicked. The value of the `onclick` property needs to be a function.

You also shouldn't use the global `Event` object as the argument here, it should receive the event that triggered the onclick.

Use this:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    openTab(event, 'newtab');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the fact that you have not rendered the element that you are trying to get with

```
document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = 'block';
```

You are first setting the onclick event and then actually adding the element to the dom on the last line

```
document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);
```

so just change the function addTab to

```
function addTab() {

    //create a new div element
    const newDiv = document.createElement('div');

    //create the id and add tab content class
    newDiv.id = "newtab"; //sets id name for div
    newDiv.classList.add("tablinks"); //sets class for div

    //give tab some text
    const tabContent = document.createTextNode("Testing the add tab button!");
    newDiv.appendChild(tabContent);

    //create the tab
    var btn = document.createElement("button"); //creates button
    btn.className = "tablinks"; //sets class for button

    //give onclick event to button
    var event = Event;

    //add the newly created element and its content into the DOM
    const currentDiv = document.getElementById("addnewtab");
    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);

    btn.onclick = openTab(event, 'newtab');
    document.getElementByClassName("tab").appendChild(btn);
}
```

There you go!